# Using multiple threads in OpenGL and SDL

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to move some of my rendering in OpenGL and some other calculations to a second thread. The problems start when I do anything related to OpenGL. 
I have read that one OpenGL context can only be used by one thread. 
I'm creating my context using this command from OpenGL:

```
SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
```

How can I generate a second context for the same window? And can I use multiple contexts on one window?